# Oracle Identify export in sql history (sql query logs)

Tags: sql, oracle

On performing export through exp command I can see the query in v$sql table, but I don't see any specific column in v$sql table stating that this particular query is fired because of the used export command.

Is there any way to identify that a particular entry in v$sql (or any other log table) is because of the export command?

Comment: I'd check `dba_datapump_sessions` joining with `v$session` and `v$sql` but not sure if that would help AFTER the process is done.

Answer (score 0):

I would use v$session or v$active_session_history(if you have a license for the diagnostic pack):

```
select sql.sql_text
from v$sqlarea sql,
     v$session sess
where sql.sql_id = sess.sql_id
and (sess.program like 'exp%');
```

or something like that if you want to monitor datapump sessions:

```
select sql.sql_text
from
   v$session sess,
   dba_datapump_sessions dp,
   v$sqlarea sql
where
   sess.saddr = dp.saddr
and sess.sql_id = sql.sql_id;
```

Comment: That wouldn't catch an export done using `dbms_datapump`.